# Slicing to extract maximum values along an axis, in an ndarray

Tags: arrays, numpy, math, slice

I'm trying to find the indices of the maximum values along a particular axis (0) for a 3D ndarray, and then use those indices to slice out those values (and the corresponding values from a second, parallel array).  For example,

```
> a = np.random.randint(10, 100, 24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
> print(a)
array([[[94, 22, 96, 44],
        [11, 85, 39, 85],
        [58, 43, 48, 84]],

       [[84, 58, 51, 30],
        [74, 89, 90, 11],
        [90, 54, 94, 20]]])
```

Now, I'm interested in the indices which give the values that are the maximum over the zeroth axis, i.e.

```
> a[inds]
array([[94, 58, 96, 44],
       [74, 89, 90, 85,],
       [90, 54, 94, 84,]])
```

Using `a.argmax()` gives which 0th-axis index is the maximum, i.e.

```
> a.argmax(axis=0)
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

But this won't work for slicing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) upon creating the range arrays along the rest of the axes/dims, like so -

```
m,n = a.shape[1:]
Y,Z = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
Y_max_axis0 = a[inds,Y,Z]
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]: 
array([[[94, 22, 96, 44],
        [11, 85, 39, 85],
        [58, 43, 48, 84]],

       [[84, 58, 51, 30],
        [74, 89, 90, 11],
        [90, 54, 94, 20]]])

In [16]: inds = a.argmax(axis=0)

In [17]: m,n = a.shape[1:]
    ...: Y,Z = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
    ...: Y_max_axis0 = a[inds,Y,Z]
    ...: 

In [18]: Y_max_axis0
Out[18]: 
array([[94, 58, 96, 44],
       [74, 89, 90, 85],
       [90, 54, 94, 84]])
```

A more explicit way to create those range arrays and then indexing -

```
In [19]: a[inds,np.arange(a.shape[1])[:,None], np.arange(a.shape[2])]
Out[19]: 
array([[94, 58, 96, 44],
       [74, 89, 90, 85],
       [90, 54, 94, 84]])
```

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I need to brush up (a lot) on my advanced indexing... but is there a simple reason why the indices to the third axis (`np.arange(a.shape[2])`) don't need to be broadcast to an additional dimension (i.e. `np.arange(a.shape[2])[:, None]`)?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Nah, we don't need to. That's why `np.arange(a.shape[2])` as shown in the `explicit-way` works as well. But using an additonal dim as given by : `np.ogrid` (shown earlier), where we have `np.arange(a.shape[2])[None]` doesn't hurt either.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix `inds` would have dims of `(m,n)`. We need to extend `np.arange(m)` because its along the first axis of `inds`, while `np.arange(n)` is along the second axis of `inds`. So, we need to extend the first range array and not the second one, as the second one would automatically extend along the first axis of `inds` upon indexing.